# AKKA clustering: send and recieve actor messages between 2 remote nodes

Tags: sbt, akka, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I have 2 project (sbt), say `projectA and projectB`. projectA dependsOn projectB. How do i configure akka cluster such that both the projects passes messages using actors?
Both projectA and projectB forms a cluster with seed -nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a message to a specific actor you can look up remote actors via actorSelection:

```
val selection context.actorSelection("akka.tcp://actorSystemName@10.0.0.1:2552/user/actorName")
```

Lots of details in the docs here: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/remoting.html

Of you can make use of a feature like [ClusterSharding](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-sharding.html) or [ClusterSingleton](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/cluster-singleton.html) where you don't need to create the actors, just send messages and Akka will create them for you.

Comment: Those configuration setting are mandatory : akka {
  actor {
    provider = remote
  }
  remote {
    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
 }
}